# I got the error Uncaught InvalidValueError: setIcon: in property url: not a string when display map pin

Tags: php, google-maps

my code is like following

```
function createPod(pod_point, pod_info, image_url,car_count,car_name,incident_id,sBookingType,lat,lon,area_id) {

    if(old_area == ''){
     contentString = '<a href="incident.php?id='+incident_id+'&lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon+'">'+car_name+'</a>';
    }
    if(old_area == area_id){
        contentString += '<br/><a href="incident.php?id='+incident_id+'&lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon+'">'+car_name+'</a>';
    }else{
        contentString = '<br/><a href="incident.php?id='+incident_id+'&lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon+'">'+car_name+'</a>';
    }
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    pod_icon = new google.maps.Marker({
        url: image_url
    });

    var pod_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pod_point,
        map: map,
        icon: pod_icon
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(pod_marker, 'click', function ()
    {
        infowindow.open(map,pod_marker);
    });

    old_area = area_id;
    return pod_marker;
}

function createCarsFromArray(carsArray,installation_location) {

    var availableIcons = [
        ['\\localhost\test\1.png'],
        ['\\localhost\test\2.png'],
        ['\\localhost\test\3.png'],
    ];

    var i = 0;
    carsArray.forEach(function(entry) {

        var podInfoPanel="";
        var iconLoc = availableIcons[entry[3]];

        createPod(new google.maps.LatLng(entry[1], entry[2]),podInfoPanel,iconLoc,0,entry[5],entry[0],entry[6],entry[1], entry[2],entry[7]);

        i++;
    });
}
```

but it was generating error and not display icon images

I am adding dynamic url for icon images , with the function parameter 
but some how it says url is not a string 
not able to find out the solution ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue

Comment: the `icon`-property of `pod_marker` should be set to `image_url`  (the creation of `pod_icon` is redundant)

Comment: And incorrect (`pod_icon = new google.maps.Marker({url: image_url});` is not an icon or a string, it is a google.maps.Marker...)

Comment: You can see in the function , createCarsFromArray( carsArray,installation_location) ,   var iconLoc = availableIcons[entry[3]]; is getting values from the  availableIcons array. so image_url will be one of the value of array (availableIcons) , but when i passing image_url value for pod_icon = new google.maps.Marker({url: image_url}); it was generating error , as it says image_url is not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code it seems, you are directly assigning path of icon from the array, **at here**:

```
var iconLoc = availableIcons[entry[3]];
```

replace this with

```
var iconLoc = String(availableIcons[entry[3]]);
```

It should work.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: thanks , yes exactly this is the answer , when is set var iconLoc = String(availableIcons[entry[3]]); as string it works perfectly